# jQuery UI Accordion Menu - Keep panel open if user clicks on a link in that panel

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm creating a jQuery accordion menu. I need the correct panel to be open when one of the sub-links are clicked.

So if "Intro" is clicked on under "Consulting", the user would go to the "Intro" page and the "Consulting" panel would be open. Or if "Value" is clicked on under "RPO", the "RPO" panel would stay open when the user is taken to that page, etc. Is there a way to do this?

```
  <ul id="nav-side" class="accordion">
    <li class="accordion-title"><a href="#">RPO</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/rpo/index.php">Value</a></li>
        <li><a href="/rpo/solution-competencies.php">Solution Competencies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/rpo/rpo-models.php">Defined RPO Models</a></li>
        <li><a href="/rpo/program-management.php">Dedicated Program Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="/rpo/solution-planning.php">Solution Planning &amp; Implementation</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-title"><a href="#">CONSULTING</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/consulting/index.php">Intro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-title"><a href="#">CRM</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

js:

```
    $(function() {
    var icons = {
      header: "ui-icon-plusthick",
      activeHeader: "ui-icon-minusthick"
    };
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
      icons: icons,
            heightStyle: "content"
    });
    $( "#toggle" ).button().click(function() {
      if ( $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" ) ) {
        $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", null );
      } else {
        $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", icons );
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Where is your javascript? It looks like you're binding selectors are a little too aggressive.

Comment: Updated to include the js

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Accordion - Keep panel open according to page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817904/jquery-ui-accordion-keep-panel-open-according-to-page)