# Opening Jquery Accordion via url hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Hello I am working on a site that uses a jquery accordion. The customer is asking me to make it that they can link to individual accordion panels from a different page.

I am not sure how to do it preferably using a url # (hash). Can someone please tell me what I would need to do. My current code can be seen at: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lgehman93/590ytqv2/)

For quick reference this is the code that triggers the accordion:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion').accordion({
        defaultOpen: 'section1'
    });
    //some_id section1 in demo 
});
```

Comment: Think this has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861030/jquery-accordion-opening-a-box-based-on-href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this if you are coming from another page with a hash:

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
    defaultOpen: window.location.hash != '' ? window.location.hash.substring(1) : 'section1'
}); //some_id section1 in demo
```

One problem with this approach though is that because you are using the hash, it will jump to that point in the page

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I wanted. I just added some additional code that scrolled it to the top immediately and that does the job! Thanks!